# can i use narrow the Type i want to instantiate with Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: vb.net, types, dictionary, activator

i got a large branch of Types that all got the same superclass and interface.

SuperClass: AbstractPackage
Interface: IPackage

Types made with this.

Package0....Package723

i use Activator.CreateInstance to create a new instance of the packages, depending og the pattern, recieved from a UDP bytestream.

i got all the registered packages, in a New Dictionary(Of UInt32, Type).

the Uint32 is the package number (0-723) and the Type, is any of the Package0 - Package723 Types.

problem is, that Activator.CreateInstance creates any type of class, and i was wondering if i could narrow the scope Down?

i wanted to make the Dictionary(and Activator.CreateInstance) to only accept Packages.
is that posable?
thanks

Comment: Whatever problem you are trying to solve, very unclear, having 724 types with a name like that can't be the right solution :)  If you need a "package number" to distinguish types of messages then just add it as a field to the message.

Comment: i started out with 1 gineric package, but problem is, each package, can contain diffrent types of data, and each package are designed to contain that data.

For instance, Package 500, containts 
small endian int
small endian int
small endian int
small endian int
small endian 32 byte string

and package 232 contains
small endian int
small endian int
small endian int
small endian int
small endian 8 byte string
small endian 8 byte string
large endian bool
large endian bool
large endian bool
large endian bool
large endian bool
large endian bool
large endian bool
null
null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a sligth change as Hans Passant pointed out for me, i might have been overthinking it.

here is my new method ( i still need to add all the classes Again, but now i atleast know what types it generate.

```
Public Function getPackage(ByVal bytes() As Byte) As APackage
        Dim pkgbytes As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}
        Dim o As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 8 To 11
            pkgbytes(o) = bytes(i)
            o += 1
        Next

        Dim package As APackage

        Dim iT As UInt32 = UByteChunk.getUInt32(pkgbytes)
        Select Case iT
            Case 0
                '0 Acknowledge
                package = New Package0(bytes)
            Case 152
                '152 EventCall
                package = New Package152(bytes)
            Case 157, 162, 165, 166
                ' 157 Event Extension
                ' 162 Event Delta Call
                ' 165 
                ' 166 Event Call Logging
                package = New PackageCall(bytes)
            Case 174
                '174 Event Targeting
                package = New Package174(bytes)
            Case 187, 188
                '187 SIP Rx
                '188 SIP Tx
                package = New PackageSIP(bytes)
            Case 93, 501, 502, 626
                '93 Version
                '501 Info
                '502 Info 2
                '626 License
                package = New PackageText(bytes)
            Case 563
                '563 System Endpoint
                package = New Package563(bytes)
            Case Else
                package = New PackageDefault(bytes)
        End Select

        Return package
    End Function
```